# 5 digit PIN into a 24 bit value

Tags: hex, ascii

I have a task where I need to convert a 5 digit PIN into a 24 bit value, split into three bytes which is then sent to a database as a string using a carriage return [0D]. The guide says that each byte is a hexadecimal value of the corresponding ASCII character.

I have written code that converts the 5 digit PIN into a hex number which is then split into three parts to form the three bytes. I have written a program to test the code and it works well until one of the bytes become 0D which also signifies a carriage return.

For example: PIN 67085 converts to 1060D in hex and is sent as bytes of [01][06][0D]. The 0D byte seems to be prematurely finalising the string and so returning an incorrect result from the database.

I a bit of a noob when it comes to decimal / hexidecimal / ASCII conversion... how do I convert the PIN into the required string without triggering a carriage return before the end of the string?

Comment: My guess is that you've misunderstood the directions and what they mean by "sent ... as a string" is that they want the 24-bit hex value to be encoded as 6 ASCII characters (in this case '0','1','0','6','0','D') followed by the '\x0D' carriage return.  It's also possible that they want the bytes sent just as you're already sending them and they will avoid the problem by taking exactly three bytes regardless of value before they look for a '\x0D' end character, but that's much less likely. Can you paste their original wording into your question?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I just realised that I was using the carriage return as a start point when parsing the return data so the issue is actually that my code was catching the OD too early in the string when they appeared in the return data.